# Tab navigation using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, navigation

I'm loading tab contents using reactjs conditional rendering. I have done it for 2 tabs successfully. But now i have a need of loading components for 3 tabs. How to do it using conditional rendering? Or is conditional rendering the correct way of doing this?

**Code for 2 tabs**

```
    class InternalGroupsPage extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                showPostTab: true,
            };

            this.state = {
                showDetailsTab: false,
            };

            this.post_tab = this.post_tab.bind(this);
            this.detail_tab = this.detail_tab.bind(this);

        }

        componentDidMount() {

            this.setState({
                showPostTab: true,
            });

        }

        post_tab() {

            this.setState({
                showPostTab: true,
                showDetailsTab: false,
            });
        }

        detail_tab() {

            this.setState({
                showPostTab: false,
                showDetailsTab: true,
            });

        }

        render() {

            return (

                <div className="body_clr">

                    <div className="group_page_header">

                       <div className="group_page_header_tabs">

                            <div className="tab_buttons_div">
                                <a className="grp_tab_btns" onClick={this.post_tab}>Posts</a>
                                <a className="grp_tab_btns" onClick={this.detail_tab}>Details</a>
                            </div>

                       </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="">

                        {this.state.showPostTab ? <GroupPost/> : <GroupDetails/>}

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Here it's fine because i have only 2 tabs. How can i handle it if there's 3 tabs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case instead of using `bool`, use `string` to identify the tab and use `switch` case to `render` the corresponding component, Write it like this:

```
<div className="">
   {this.renderTab()}                        
</div>
```

Inside `renderTab` method use `switch case` and return the component:

```
renderTab(){

   switch(this.state.showPostTab){
       case 'A': return <A/>;
       case 'B': return <B/>;
       case 'C': return <C/>;
   }

}
```

By this way you can handle n no of tabs.

Check the working example:

```js
var Post = () => <div> Post </div>;
var Detail = () => <div> Detail </div>;
var XYZ = () => <div> XYZ </div>;

class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {tabName: 'post'}
   }
   
   tabChange(tabName){
      this.setState({tabName});
   }
   
   renderTab(){
      switch(this.state.tabName){
         case 'post': return <Post/>
         case 'detail': return <Detail/>
         case 'xyz': return <XYZ/>
      }
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <div className="tab_buttons_div">
                <a className="grp_tab_btns" onClick={this.tabChange.bind(this,'post')}>  Posts | </a>
                <a className="grp_tab_btns" onClick={this.tabChange.bind(this,'detail')}>  Details | </a>
                <a className="grp_tab_btns" onClick={this.tabChange.bind(this,'xyz')}>  XYZ  </a>
            </div>
            {this.renderTab()}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more further please?

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if you need help in this :)

Comment: Thank you! your solution was perfect

Answer (score 1):

Store an id for the tab in state, like:

```
this.state = {
  tab: 'post',
};
```

Then in render check which tab is active and render based on it. You can create a tab mapping object for this purpose.

```
const tabs = {
  post: () => <GroupPost />,
  details: () => <GroupDetails />,
};

const element = tabs[this.state.tab]();
return <div>{element}</div>;
```

Comment: btw, a switch is also valid like in Mayank Shukla's answer

Comment: So if i have 3 tabs, i have set individual id's for all 3 tabs?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD yes.